Magento RDS too many connections

Hi, I am facing some abnormal condition. Even though the server specs are very high and CPU usage is only 2.5%.
Suddenly there is a lock on inventory table some times on order grid and then for every new request rds is having a new session.
Any assistance will be highly appreciated.
Thanks
